# What is the point of this neo4j kernel property : all_stores_total_mapped_memory_size

Tags: neo4j

...
if it is the total sum of all the other memory mapped properties:

```
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory
```

Should I

- a) set `all_stores_total_mapped_memory_size` to the sum of the above properties?
  or
- b) not set it at all (it will be calculated from the above) ?

Neo4j 1.9.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) not set it at all

It's calculated internally as sum of the above.